# How do I get 5.1 surround sound via HDMI to work?

Tags: sound

I’m on Freya with all the latest updates. I’d like to use 5.1 surround sound output via HDMI, but the sound settings only offer me stereo output via HDMI. I tested Xubuntu 15.04 (Vivid), booted from a thumb drive, which gave me surround options via HDMI out of the box.

Is there any way to get whatever is needed from a ppa or other source? Or do I have to migrate that machine to Vivid?

Comment: Which graphics card do you have? Might be a driver issue. Which player do you use? Might be a player issue. Etc. Please provide some more information.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using pulse audio?

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

open it and check the configuration tab and you will find options there. I am using elementary OS and found the same option though haven't used it.